# Tabulating points from CSV that are within 1 km of points from another CSV using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, merge

I have two sets of data. One that is from a csv and contains a relatively small amount of data (we will call location data), and another csv that contains a larger dataset that contains environmental data.

I want to create a separate csv file that contains all the environmental data that is within 1 km of the location data.

**For example,**

If temperature data comes within a 1 km radius of 1 or more points from the locations data, I want to create a new file that contains all the data that is in that 1 km radius.

How should I go about doing this using QGIS?

See the image I attached. The pink points are the location data and the small points is the environmental data. I only want to look at the data that overlaps with the pink.

Keep in mind the pink data points are styled and there is a 2000 m diameter.

[image]

Comment: load your csv into a spatial database and save time by using the spatial functions of the database.

Comment: If you wish to also ask about ArcGIS Desktop then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Did you work with spatial join and buffer ?